# Not decreasing sequence that converges to 0 : can the sequence of the indexes for which the sequence decreases be bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider a strictly positive sequence $\{u_n\}$ of real numbers (i.e. $\forall n, u_n >0$). Suppose that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} u_n = 0$ and that $\{u_n\}$ *is not decreasing*.

Consider the sequence $\{l_n\}$ defined by : $\forall n \in \mathbb N, l_n := \min\left\{i-n,\text{ such that } u_i\leq u_n,\forall i> n\right\}$.

This sequence counts the number of iterations needed before a term of the sequence $\{u_n\}$, smaller than the current term, appears. **My question is whether this sequence is bounded.**

If $\{u_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence, it is clear that $\forall n \in \mathbb N, l_n = 1$, so in this case, the sequence is bounded.

But my question concerns the case where $\{u_n\}$ *is not decreasing* !

Given that the sequence $\{u_n\}$ converges towards $0$, even if it is not a decreasing sequence, the sequence $\{l_n\}$ is well defined.

In fact, given an iterate $u_n$, the convergence to $0$ of the sequence can be written as : \begin{equation}(*)\text{ there exists } i(n) \in \mathbb N, \text{ such that } \forall k \geq i(n), u_k \leq u_n\end{equation}
So we just have to take $l_n = \min\left\{i(n)-n, \text{where } i(n) \text{ verifies }(*)\right\}$.

As we just see, $\{l_n\}$ is a (non-negative) well defined sequence. **But is $\{l_n\}$ bounded?**

I tried to think of a counter-example, but I have the impression that this result looks true (I mean, that the sequence is bounded).
However, I don't know how to prove it. Do you have any clues?

Comment: Consider 1/1, 1/2, 1/2, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5, .....

Comment: But, this sequence is decreasing, right ? An exemple of sequence that tends to 0 and not decreasing could be a sequence like $u_n = \frac{1}{n}$ if $n$ is odd and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ if $n$ is even

Comment: 1/ It's not a strictly decreasing sequence, 2/ I'm sure you can modify it slightly so that it's not a non-decreasing sequence either. EG 1/1, 1/2, 1/1.9, 1/3, 1/2.9, 2/2.8, 1/4, 1/3.9, 1/3.8, 1/3.7, 1/5, 1/4.9, 1/4.8, 1/4.7, 1/4.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$.10,\;.11,$$
$$.0100,\;.0101,\;.0110,\;.0111,$$
$$.001000,\;.001001,\;.001010,\;.001011,\;.001100,\;.001101,\;.001110,\;.001111,$$
$$.00010000,\;.00010001,\;.00010010,\;.00010011,\;.00010100,\;.00010101,\;.00010110,\;.00010111, \\ .00011000,\;.00011001,\;.00011010,\;.00011011,\;.00011100,\;.00011101,\;.00011110,\;.00011111,$$
$$\cdots$$

Comment: Oh ok, I see ! Do you have any idea of an additional hypothesis to put on the $\{u_n\}$ sequence to avoid this kind of counter-example, please?

Comment: @OussamaZekri Very unlikely, other than requiring something that quickly implies "there exists a $K$ such that for any $i$, there exists a $k\leq K$ such that $ u_i > u_{i+k}$.  Otherwise, there is no reason why $\{l_n\}$ must be bounded.  If you're thinking that "well, $u_n$ gets really small, maybe we can make such an argument", then consider $\{ 1/u_n \}$ instead.

Comment: @CalvinLin That is absolutely true, thank you so much for this comment, which really clarifies my vision of the problem.