# Not decreasing sequence that converges to 0: sufficient condition for the sequence of indexes for which the sequence decreases to be bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Consider a strictly positive sequence $\{u_n\}$ of real numbers (i.e. $\forall n, u_n >0$). Suppose that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} u_n = 0$ and that $\{u_n\}$ *is not decreasing*.

Consider the sequence $\{l_n\}$ defined by : $\forall n \in \mathbb N, l_n := \min\left\{i-n,\text{ such that } u_i < u_n,\forall i> n\right\}$.

This sequence counts the number of iterations needed before a term of the sequence $\{u_n\}$, smaller than the current term, appears. In a [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4831618/non-decreasing-sequence-that-converges-to-0-can-the-sequence-of-the-indexes-fo), I wondered whether such a sequence could be said to be bounded (when $\{u_n\}$ is not decreasing), but the answer is no: I've been given a counter-example. (See the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4831618/non-decreasing-sequence-that-converges-to-0-can-the-sequence-of-the-indexes-fo)).

I'm now wondering **what kind of conditions need to be added to the sequence $\{u_n\}$ for the sequence $\{l_n\}$ to become bounded.**

At first, I thought of a "[Cauchy sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence)" condition, but I have the impression that the counterexample $\{u_n\}$ given in the previous post is indeed a Cauchy sequence, yet the associated sequence $\{l_n\}$ is not bounded.

I'm really having trouble visualizing the kind of condition that would imply boundedness on $\{l_n\}$, except when the $\{u_n\}$ sequence is decreasing. (In fact, if $\{u_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence, it is clear that $\forall n \in \mathbb N, l_n = 1$, so in this case, the sequence is bounded). Do you have any clues?

Comment: Non-decreasing and not decreasing are very different. Please correct the title.

Comment: That's true, edited.

Comment: @OussamaZekri In complete spaces like $\mathbb{R}$ the Cauchy sequences coincide with the convergent sequences. So, nothing new would come from using a "Cauchy sequence condition".

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes, absolutely, it must come from something else, and I have the feeling that we can find a weaker condition than forcing the $\{u_n\}$ sequence to decay.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean $u_i<u_n$, rather than $u_i\leq u_n$? If that is what you meant I will change the inequality sign on the infs in my answer to a strict inequality.

Comment: @ChrisSanders Yes you are right, I will edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $u_n>0$ converges to $0$ but isn't a decreasing sequence,

each of the following is equivalent:

"$l_n$ is bounded"

"there exists $K$ such that $\inf B_{j+1}<\inf B_j$ for all $j$, where $B_j$ denotes $\{u_{jK},u_{jK+1},\cdots,u_{(j+1)K-1}\}$"

"there exists $K$ such that $c_{j+1}<c_j$ for all $j$, where $\displaystyle c_j$ denotes $\inf_{n\leq jK}u_n$"

"the gap between any pair of consecutive elements of $T$ is bounded, where $T$ denotes the set of integers $\tau$ such that $u_i>u_\tau$ whenever $i<\tau$"

Not too hard to prove.

Comment: What you wrote down $a$ refers to the $u$ sequence, doesn't it? $\{x_n\}$ too?

Comment: @OussamaZekri J'y ai rajouté des choses. D'ailleurs dans quel contexte votre question vous est venue à l'esprit?

Comment: Merci! Je vais étudier ça de plus près. En fait, je suis dans un espace vectoriel normé $E$ et je dispose d'une suite $\{u_k\}$ qui converge vers un point $c$ d'un convexe fermé $C$ de $E$. Bien qu'elle converge, cette suite n'est pas Fejèr monotone. Pour prouver un certain théorème, j'ai besoin de montrer qu'il existe un entier $l$ **fini** tel que $\forall k, \lVert u_k -c \rVert \geq \lVert u_{k+l} -c \rVert$. J'arrive à construire une suite d'entiers $\{l_k\}$ qui vérifie cette propriété, mais j'ai besoin que cette suite soit bornée pour introduire $l = \max_{k} \{ l_k\}$.

Comment: Bien-sûr, Il faut que j'utilise des propriétés spécifiques de ma suite, mais je me demandais s'il était possible de trouver une condition suffisante assez facile à prouver. Je serai ravi de continuer cette discussion par mail avec vous pour vous donner plus de détails sur les motivations de cette recherche, et sur la suite en elle même. Vous pouvez trouver mon mail sur le site qui apparaît dans ma bio :) Merci infiniement d'avance.

Comment: Et je suis particulièrement intéressé par la dernière équivalence que vous avez proposé. Il se trouve que la suite la vérifie. Cependant, j’ai du mal à voir comment montrer l’implication de cette condition vers le caractère borné de $\{l_k\}$. (Pas de problèmes pour le sens direct)